# DbUp - Is it Possible to Deploy using Manifest File

Tags: sql-server, dbup

We currently use Dbup for SQL deployment. I would like to configure Dbup to allow for the use of a manifest file for deployment. I envision a directory with a manifest file for each release, the manifest file containing the file name (or perhaps path and name) of the file that should be deployed at the next upgrade. So Dbup, rather than running all the scripts it hasn't run yet, would got look at the latest manifest file, and would only run the scripts in the manifest file. Is this possible with existing Dbup functionality? If not, how could I accomplish it?

Comment: Are you currently using the `WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly` approach?

Comment: @StewartRitchie I'm using WithScriptsFromFileSystem

Comment: I could switch to WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly if it will help accomplish the goal..Maybe there's some built in way to do this already and I just don't know about it.

Comment: The `WithScripts` method gives the most control. Create a class to read your manifest file and return a collection of `SqlScript` objects with the contents of your source files.